# How to loop through a CSV file with multiple values in one of its columns?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a CSV file containing multiple values in one of its columns.

Basically it look like:

```
Name        NewName     Groups    
UserA       User01      IT Group;GroupB;Doc Users Group;GroupD
```

I need to know how to loop through the column to get all group names from it.

I used the following code but it doesn't work. I think the problem is there are spaces between words in group names and PowerShell treats the whole cell as one group name.

```
foreach ($user in (Import-Csv "$env:USERPROFILE\desktop\info.csv")) {
    $oldusername = $user.name
    $newusername = $user.NewName
    $groups      = $user.Groups -split ";"

    foreach ($group in $groups) {
        Remove-ADGroupMember $group -Members $oldusername -Confirm:$false -Verbose
        Add-ADGroupMember $group -Members $newusername -Verbose
    }
}
```

So I should get:

```
Remove-ADGroupMember IT Group
```

but I get:

```
Remove-ADGroupMember IT Group GroupB Doc Users Group GroupD
```

which obviously doesn't work.

Comment: Your 'csv' file doesn't seem to use commas.  Is it tab-separated?  If, so, you need to add -Delimiter "`t" to your Import-Csv cmdlet.

Comment: Are you *sure* you didn't typo `remove-adgroupmember $groups` with an `s`? Because it looks like it should work...

Answer (score 0):

I didn't copy/paste the csv file I just showed you the values in the file.

The proper csv content is:
"Name","NewName","Groups"
"UserA","User01","IT Group;GroupB;Doc Users Group;GroupD"

I think I solved the puzzle with the loop. The code which works is:

```
foreach ($user in (Import-Csv "$env:USERPROFILE\desktop\info.csv")) {
$oldusername = $user.name
$newusername = $user.NewName
$groups      = $user.Groups 

foreach ($group in $groups -split ";") {
    Remove-ADGroupMember $group -Members $oldusername -Confirm:$false -Verbose
    Add-ADGroupMember $group -Members $newusername -Verbose
} }
```